# AWK: splitting a string into pieces

Tags: string, awk, split

I've been trying to solve this problem by myself, I've looked for some help on Google, but I can't go ahead anyway. Any help you can provide will be very thanked!

So, I have a string, for example:

```
CTGGCAAGAAAGAAATGTGGAATGGCAACAAAGAAAGGAAAAAAAATCAATACTGGCTGATGCAGTTTC
```

And I'm looking for this output:

```
CTG GCA AGA AAG AAA TGT GGA ATG GCA ACA AAG AAA GGA AAA AAA ATC AAT ACT GGC TGA TGC AGT TTC
```

I could do it very fast in Python or Perl, but I need to use here AWK.

Thank you very much, people! I appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '{gsub(/.../,"& ")}1' <<< CTGGCAAGAAAGAAATGTGGAATGGCAACAAAGAAAGGAAAAAAAATCAATACTGGCTGATGCAGTTTC
```

```
CTG GCA AGA AAG AAA TGT GGA ATG GCA ACA AAG AAA GGA AAA AAA ATC AAT ACT GGC TGA TGC AGT TTC
```